# Собрать header only dll с помощью cmake

Tags: c++, dll, cmake

Хочу собрать dll с помощью `cmake`. Использую следующий код:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(app)

set(DLL_SOURCE_FILES library.hpp)

add_library(dll SHARED ${DLL_SOURCE_FILES})
```

Получаю ошибку `CMake can not determine linker language for target`. Насколько я понял по [документации](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/add_library.html) к команде `add_library`, нужно указать как минимум 1 `.cpp` файл, однако моя библиотека содержит только шаблонные классы, поэтому таких файлов у меня нет. Как быть?

Comment: Думаю, понятие header-only DLL лишено смысла :-/

Comment: Можно сделать DLL только для некоторых предопределенных параметров типа шаблонов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак.

DLL содержит в себе машинный код. Однако в случае с шаблонными сущностями он не может быть сгенерирован заранее.

Генерация кода для шаблонных классов производится в самый последний момент, при сборке самой программы, а именно при первом упоминании конкретной специализации шаблона. Именно тогда абстракция, существующая исключительно в воображении компилятора, обретает форму конкретных машинных команд.